# Conditional type add a extra generic got compiler error

Tags: typescript

According typescript official [Advanced Type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) section, I want to got a custom type like following.

```js
// This is typescript official example of documentation
declare function f<T extends boolean>(x: T): T extends true ? string : number;
let x = f(Math.random() < 0.5) // Type is 'string | number'

// This is what I do
declare function foo<Q, T extends boolean>(x: T): T extends true ? Q : number;

let res = foo<boolean>(true) // failed, expect res is boolean type, but got Compiler error message: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1
```

### I have tried to give T a default boolean type,But I got a error result that variable res is `number | boolean`.

My problem source from [the sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIA9gHsDOAlCARwFcIcwBhLEGYAc2QG9kBfAWAChRJZEUNs+MgAdqOCAB4AKgD4mnZMgAmcMHABcyKZ3YdO3aPCTIKxclgC2A3ARJlK1WgwjpIIJTjSYbRUuSo09PIcigD0AFThyFAQYMRQIF6CBDiiIOLIWFDKqnDKwDEIYAA2AJ7I4aEKyDDExcUpaeIA-JoARlhYxRBwIADcOpycEVEAksgWcADWKGYoWDDIcOjEwJ4GUEjCYFlLmwAWwABuKDFxCcgAClCWa5J4crvXtxlt5YgIWUqgDKDkvUgANoAIlq9UaYggwIAugoom1iGAarszD9kGBSsIyAgoMBtgAaZDjEAQCBKZAIfa9Oj8bw4UbpNQgYwbIwQOFVLjgQx8ExmHZWOkM-7MlCMao0sDSZAAXiWIFKhLwsqSPlSkOkMkJAEVkC43B4+eZBclfPYAk4VaZjdYhHZ-I56DIABTVRTxYqaci4kB0fFuimOuitZDa6oASk02pBYIaIkhML1rgg7k8YCgpGQzSuNwsdwkD2QmmeefEmoGHF0nG6SOWgmFTOMcsYLCWnmtAttDYB7L0HBryBwxAQSBwOAAjCq67hu6KAHSS53A4GE5igupx9XpKGadOZljh6uxQfD0c4ABMU6FjJ7C9iS5XTGQ6-B8e3wM08GKGQPQw4oVCZAAEIQK0Q51k8CxyjoLA4GKYDQLAfYUAxLFMkWaAbigABmQd9iwOpyTaFAS3zW0IW3CQQGICxiKgGQ5ARJEYKRUiy2o2joBkP8B0wrJcLlad6RvedJSomi6JdZdV2fWMKPED90QzFBf37Y8+KgAAWK96xEpA7ylb0fikx81zkt8FM-OCf0PPsAIpeIYnAQcukRbAQCPJEcFcsB3PHYtczIul5MkDjJLkQTrxFfTF2kp8X03JodyU-dbIHbzijc6hzwCl5JCM30IqWKLGwgAyHxkhKQsUr8bM4IA).

## Update.

I has resolved my problem by wrap another function according @ford04 solution

```js
interface CustomAxiosRequestConfig extends AxiosRequestConfig {
  XFullResponse?: boolean;
}

interface CustomAxiosResponse<T = any> extends AxiosResponse {
  config: CustomAxiosRequestConfig;
}

interface CustomAxiosInstance {
  get<T = any, R = CustomAxiosResponse<T>>(
    url: string,
    config?: CustomAxiosRequestConfig
  ): Promise<R>;
}

let axios = {} as CustomAxiosInstance

interface data {}

const getUser = function<T extends CustomAxiosRequestConfig>(config: T){
  return axios.get<data, T['XFullResponse'] extends true ? data : CustomAxiosResponse<data>>("/getUser", config)
}
// type is Promise<data>
let res1 = getUser({XFullResponse: true})
// type is Promise<CustomAxiosResponse<data>>
let res2 = getUser({XFullResponse: false})
```

Comment: There is no partial type argument inference in TS [yet](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242). So you either can 1) specify both parameters manually or 2) wrap `foo` with another function that only expects `Q`.

Comment: @ford04 I considered the second method,but failed.I will try again.Thanks.

Comment: There we go: [sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwB4BFAPgAoBKALniIBV4QAPDEVYAZ3gCNCIIKKkos6DKvAC8ZeE1btOPDDGQIA-PBLw6qZAFteIGAG4AsAChLgjPDg8pBYvxyDhlKhRVrJAel92IBjIMKg8Lm6oQA). But it is more code and has run-time implications opposed to first alternative.

Comment: @ford04 Thanks.I resolved my problem,I will accept your answer if you are in answer  panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not get a compile error with your snippet. But anyway, you should give 2 type parameters and then it works as expected:

```
declare function foo<Q, T extends boolean>(x: T): T extends true ? Q : number;

let res = foo<boolean, true>(true)     // res is of type boolean (T extends true)
let res = foo<boolean, false>(false)   // res is of type number (T does not extend true)
let res = foo<boolean, boolean>(true)  // res is of type number (T does not extends true)
```

Comment: Accoding offical example,sometime T can be infered by paramter,like above.so I want to also use this machinism to write less code as possible.

Answer (score 1):

For the amount of type safety you get from such a function, you can use inference on both generic parameters like this:

```js
let res: boolean = foo(true) // this works
let res_other_type: string = foo(true) // this also works
let res_error: boolean = foo(false) // this is an error
```

Note that with your function signature it's not actually possible to know what `foo` will actually return, so specifying the type here is almost as unsafe as simply returning `unknown` from `foo` and casting to `boolean`

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=56&pln=2&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwB4BFAGngBV4QAPDEVYAZ3gCNCIQpUA+ACloAuKgEoR1OgyasMMZAgD88EvBGpkAWzYgYAbgCwAKGNcM8OMxEccXHvAC8BHPzkLR8APSf4GABZYrADuODAA1symIOaWAPo4-rqxGACeAA4gIsxyWKgA5o7OrvIgHt6+AaxQEMw48CHhkUZmFiDMsbowodac3PhOiIT8iNXMpV4+-oHw0-adoUA).

Answer (score 0):

We have here two issues

- you are defining two arguments generic type and provide one (compile error)
- you are defining default value of the second as union `boolean` type

The first issue I think is understandable as when you don't provide default value, then you need to put the argument, you can understand that as function working with two arguments, no defaults means both need to be passed.

Second issue can be more tricky to understand, but your conditional type gets into both branches because this is how union types are [distributed in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types).

Type `boolean` is union `true | false`, it means your conditional type will be evaluated twice for every element of the union. So lets see how it will evaluate for such union of two elements - `true` and `false`

- `true extends true ? Q : number` // gets Q
- `false extends true ? Q : number` // gets number

The result is a union of all evaluation on every union element, so from `true | false` we get `Q | number`.

I hope I describe you the issues you are facing. I cannot help you more because I don't understand what is the goal of your type.

Comment: I didn't describe my goals clearly.So I updated my problem which added the sample playground.Thank you to the very detailed answer.